# Конструктор форм. Структура таблиц

Tags: php, база-данных, форма, конструктор

Есть веб-приложение на PHP, в котором пользователь может сам создавать формы с помощью конструктора.

С сохранением информации о формах (т.е. информакция о инпутах, селектах и прочих элементах, которые содержит форма) проблем не возникло.
Есть две таблички - одна хранит формы, другая элементы формы.

Но есть другая проблема - как хранить данные, сохраняемые с помощью этих форм?
Все эти данные в одной таблице?

Comment: А что представляет из себя "форма", есть ли в системе понятие "документ" или еще что то подобное (если есть то по идее одна форма видимо обслуживает не более одного документа, но документ может редактироваться в нескольких формах). Короче, если документ есть - то под него можно создавать таблицу с колонками требуемых типов. По крайней мере последующая работа с данными будет значительно проще. Выдавать выходные формы, собрать какие нибудь суммы явно проще по нормальной реляционной таблице, чем по таблице форма-поле-значение

Comment: В системе есть понятие модуля.
Почти все модули содержат форму для добавления записи(обычная форма в модальном окне - инпуты, селекты, выбор даты и т. д.), его редактирования и отображение записей в виде таблицы.

"Короче, если документ есть - то под него можно создавать таблицу с колонками требуемых типов."
Т.е. динамически создавать таблицы и колонки в ней?

Comment: Ну да, почему бы и нет. там конечно надо будет все как следует проработать, особенно когда пользователь захочет поменять тип колонки, удалить поле или еще. alter не всегда могут пройти ...

Answer (score 1):

Если эти формы можно как то разделить на небольшое количество категорий то можно хранить в разных таблицах. А так в одной.

Comment: Удобнее, конечно, хранить в одной таблице.
Но тогда в этой таблице придётся под каждый тип выделить отдельную колонку (Date, Datetime, Time и т. д.).
Ведь данные могут быть разные.

Comment: по одной таблице практически нереально будет собирать какие нибудь суммарные данные. Представьте, что в форме десяток полей, среди которых есть например дата и надо получить суммы всех значений за месяц. по одной таблице со всеми формами оно конечно собирается, но скорость работы будет никакая